# How to fix "System.TypeInitializationException" error in C# connection code to OracleDB

Tags: c#, oracle

I am setting up a little monitoring script which shall check if the OracleDB is accessible. 
We have several daily exports into this DB planned with the Taskscheduler which sometimes runs into error (just Timeout, no further logging there). I want to do some research on my own and I decided to check periodically if the connection is there and then compare this to the error of the other team of my department.

I tried some code referenced in this link [Oracle How to](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/latest-news/dotnetquickstart-4119449.html). I also installed the VS2017 Developer Tools for Oracle as described.

I changed the code to my database and the following error occurs:

`System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception.'`

This is my code:

```
string conString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=xxx)(Port=xxx)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)));User Id=xx;Password=xx;";

OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = conString;
con.Open();

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select first_name from employees where department_id = 60"; // some query

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + reader.GetString(0)); // some output
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

InnerException:

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.`

Comment: What namespace are you using? Oracle.DataAccess or Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Comment: using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

Comment: I think there's usually an inner exception that contains the actual details of the problem.

Comment: updated...but what file does he want to find?!

Comment: Which version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess do you use?

Comment: Does it work with `reader.GetValue(0).ToString()` or `Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(0))`? What is the result?

Comment: It's telling you what it's failing to find - `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`. You might try adding an explicit reference to it in your project to see if it resolves the matter.